# Why my Symfony form doesn't show errors while being rendered from Controller?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, easyadmin

I am using EasyAdminBundle and wanted to create change password functionality for admin panel. Everything works correctly, however there is a problem, that form doesn't show errors, when RepeatedType fields are not the same and when oldPassword is incorrect.
Errors are correctly being sent from formType to controller, however the twig doesn't display them.
ChangeAdminPasswordType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('oldPassword', PasswordType::class, [
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank(),
                    new Length(['min' => 4])
                ],
            ])
            ->add('newPassword', RepeatedType::class, [
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'error_bubbling' => true,
                'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
                'first_options'  => ['label' => 'New Password'],
                'second_options' => ['label' => 'Repeat New Password'],

            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'],
            ])
        ;
    }
```

ChangeAdminPasswordController

```
public function changeAdminPassword(Request $request): Response
    {
        $ex = new ChangeAdminPasswordDto();
        $form = $this->formFactory->create(ChangeAdminPasswordType::class, $ex);

        $view = $form->createView();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            if (($this->changeAdminPassword)($this->getUser(), $form->getData())) {
                return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_dashboard');
            }
            $form->addError(new FormError('Current password is not correct'));
        }

        return $this->render('bundles/EasyAdminBundle/changeAdminPassword.html.twig', [
            'form' => $view,
        ]);
    }
```

changAdminPassword.html.twig

```
{% extends '@EasyAdmin/layout.html.twig' %}
{% block content_title %}
    <div class="content-header-title">
        <h1 class="title">
            Change password
        </h1>
    </div>

{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    <div class="col-md6 col-xxl-5">
        <div class="field-text form-group">
            {{ form_label(form.oldPassword) }}
            <div class="form-widget">
                {{ form_widget(form.oldPassword, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field-text form-group">
            {{ form_label(form.newPassword.first) }}
            <div class="form-widget">
                {{ form_widget(form.newPassword.first, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field-text form-group">
            {{ form_label(form.newPassword.second) }}
            <div class="form-widget">
                {{ form_widget(form.newPassword.second, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page-actions">
        {{ form_row(form.save) }}
    </div>
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Try adding for each widget for example: `form_errors(form.newPassword.first)` etc..

Comment: Already tried that actually. Still not the case.

Comment: Try changing `'form' => $view` to `'form' => $form->createView()`. You're creating the view before the submission..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating the form view before the submission here `$view = $form->createView();`. Any error messages wont be rendered after any validations...

Change this:

```
return $this->render('bundles/EasyAdminBundle/changeAdminPassword.html.twig', 
    [
        'form' => $view,
    ]);
```

To this:

```
return $this->render('bundles/EasyAdminBundle/changeAdminPassword.html.twig', 
    [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
```